# Upload new website to S3 and Route 53 failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I'm new to all AWS. I followed a tutorial on how to upload static webpage to S3 and create DNS with Route 53.

I created two buckets (`carbomania.co.uk` and `www.carbomania.co.uk`). The last one is redirected to the first one.

I owned `carbomania.co.uk` with Route 53 and added a Hosted Zone for it. I added an alias record set which points to the `carbomania.co.uk` bucket.

When I go to the endpoint in S3 for carbomania.co.uk it's all good, the simple `index.html` is loaded: `carbomania.co.uk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

But when I go to `carbomania.co.uk`, some gandi.net site is loaded (I never saw it before).

How can it be solved?

***Edited***:

Record sets:

**Name Server**:

- `ns-1577.awsdns-05.co.uk.`
- `ns-245.awsdns-30.com.`
- `ns-1221.awsdns-24.org.`
- `ns-698.awsdns-23.net.`

**SOA**:

ns-1577.awsdns-05.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

**Alias**:

carbomania.co.uk is pointing to s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

Comment: `gandi.net` provides the domain name registration for AWS. When I try to resolve `carbomania.co.uk`, it fails. This suggests it has not been correctly configured in Route 53. `whois` shows that you own the domain name, and it is pointed to AWS, so it looks like a problem with the Record Set in Route 53. Any chance you can provide the Record Set configuration you've used?

Comment: See edited section, thanks !

Comment: Have you turned on Static Website Hosting on your `carbomania.co.uk` bucket? Also, make sure your content is publicly accessible (that wouldn't be causing the current problem, but I note that I cannot see the content of that bucket).